# Can I run existing ASP.NET MVC application in Docker without converting to ASP.NET Core in Linux

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linux, docker

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC application which I want to run on Linux Ubuntu.

I have successfully build and ran an ASP.NET Core "hello world" application in Docker but I can't run my ASP.NET MVC app. I have added the docker file to create the image in my project but when I try to build it always give this error:

> "Error checking context: 'Error in pattern (obj/..): syntax error in pattern" error.

Can any one please provide reference links or solution?

Comment: use docker for windows on server 2016

Comment: What is your `FROM` statement in your Dockerfile?

Comment: FROM microsoft/iis

RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature NET-Framework-45-ASPNET"]
RUN ["powershell.exe", "Install-WindowsFeature Web-Asp-Net45"]

ADD web-app/ c:\\web-app

EXPOSE 8081
My docker file :
RUN powershell New-Website -Name 'web-app' -Port 8081 -PhysicalPath 'c:\web-app' -ApplicationPool '.NET v4.5'

ENTRYPOINT powershell

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot go to Docker on Linux, but only Docker on Windows,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/deployment/docker-aspnetmvc